# How to uninstall corrupted NPM?

Tags: apt, uninstall, nodejs, npm

Question is simple, and solution should be simple.
More details about my problem. Check `npm`:

```
~ npm -version
>> 4.0.5
~ which npm
>> /usr/local/bin/npm
```

try uninstall:

```
~ sudo apt-get remove npm
>> Package 'npm' is not installed, so not removed
```

ok, lets install it than if it isn't:

```
~ sudo apt-get install npm
npm: Depends: nodejs but it will not be installed
       Depends: node-abbrev (> = 1.0.4) but it is not installed
       Depends: node-ansi but it will not be installed
       Depends: node-archy but it will not be installed
       Depends: node-block-stream but it will not be installed
       Depends: node-fstream (> = 0.1.22) but it is not installed
       Depends: node-fstream-ignore but it is not installed
       Depends: node-github-url-from-git but he will not be installed
       Depends: node-glob (> = 3.1.21) but it is not installed
       Depends: node-graceful-fs (> = 2.0.0) but it is not installed
       Depends: node-inherits but it will not be installed
       Depends: node-ini (> = 1.1.0) but it is not installed
       Depends: node-lockfile but it will not be installed
       Depends: node-lru-cache (> = 2.3.0) but it is not installed
       Depends: node-minimatch (> = 0.2.11) but it is not installed
       Depends: node-mkdirp (> = 0.3.3) but it is not installed
       Depends: node-gyp (> = 0.10.9) but it will not be installed
       Depends: node-nopt (> = 2.1.1) but it is not installed
       Depends: node-npmlog but it will not be installed
       Depends: node-once but it will not be installed
       Depends: node-osenv but it will not be installed
       Depends: node-read but it is not installed
       Depends: node-read-package-json (> = 1.1.0) but it is not installed
       Depends: node-request (> = 2.25.0) but it will not be installed
       Depends: node-retry but it will not be installed
       Depends: node-rimraf (> = 2.2.2) but it is not installed
       Depends: node-semver (> = 2.1.0) but it is not installed
       Depends: node-sha but it will not be installed
       Depends: node-slide but it will not be installed
       Depends: node-tar (> = 0.1.18) but it is not installed
       Depends: node-which but it will not be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have delayed (held) broken packages.
```

So I can not neither install nor uninstall it.
Lets see `held`

```
~ dpkg --get-selections | grep hold
>> [no results]
```

nodejs:

```
~ nodejs -v
>> v0.12.18
```

I can not remove my npm and I can not update one. Is there any solutions for me?

---

Add more details:

```
npm uninstall npm -g
```

a lot of logs nad errors in the very end:

```
- npm@4.0.5 node_modules/npm
npm ERR! Linux 3.13.0-37-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "uninstall" "npm" "-g"
npm ERR! node v7.4.0
npm ERR! npm  v4.0.5
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/abbrev
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! syscall access

npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/abbrev'
npm ERR!  { Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/abbrev'
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'access',
npm ERR!   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/abbrev' }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /media/storage/development/projects/web/angular-app/npm-debug.log
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Uninstall it with `sudo npm uninstall npm -g`

Comment: I have just tried this instruction, details are added to the my question after separate line.

Comment: try with `sudo`

Comment: sorry forgot this command and did not read error details to the end. First opinion was `problem is in 2 different installed versions`